# Could I get some criticism on my posts?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

Backstory:

I'm active a lot lately, and I must say I try to post as high-quality posts, especially answers, as I can. I remember when I was a new user, my post quality was really low, I was getting more downvotes than upvotes and my posts kept getting edited to remove grammar issues. Still, I was getting slowly better. Now it seems to me people know what I'm talking about.

The thing is that recently, I'm not getting votes on almost all of my newer posts (especially answers). I'm not going into conclusions, but it's a bit suspicious. Here are a few of the recent low-voted posts I chose:

- [How to testfor if a player is gliding with an elytra?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291425/how-to-testfor-if-a-player-is-gliding-with-an-elytra/291445#291445) (+1 votes)
- [How to detect the winner](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258501/how-to-detect-the-winner/292463#292463) (+1 votes)
- [How do you turn hostile mobs against each other?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292583/how-do-you-turn-hostile-mobs-against-each-other/292603#292603) (+2 votes)
- [How do I trigger command blocks when a player walks in an area](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292890/how-do-i-trigger-command-blocks-when-a-player-walks-in-an-area/292898#292898) (+2 votes)
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292900/minecraft-crash/292902#292902 (-1 votes)

[Here is my user profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/143228/user143228).

The question asked here: Could I get some (a lot, if you wish, I won't mind) criticism on what's wrong on my posts? Like, what was/is wrong on them, what did I do wrong, or, generally, why don't people vote on my posts? This has been a bit... discouraging for me.

Edit: posting this here got me 6 upvotes on linked posts in total (why?).

Comment: 3/5 are asked by new users who often don't bother to vote/accept answer and leave the site after asking.

Comment: Most of those are also on Minecraft-commands questions, which typically have low vote counts in general (many are often specific to what one person wants the commands to do, so they don't attract as much traffic). In general, in cases like most of the ones you've presented - I would consider low-votes to be a general lack of community knowlege and/or interest in the area rather than an indication of anything wrong with your answers.

Comment: @user598527 I used to get approx. 1-3 votes on most of my posts. Also, almost all the upvotes I got recently were from a new-user OP.

Comment: Lack of votes doesn't mean something is wrong, Rudolf. It just means nobody is voting. Could be for any number of reasons, few of which reflect in your posts specifically.

Comment: @Frank What could those reasons be?

Comment: @user143228 apathy and laziness among other things.

Comment: @user143228 One cause: the questions aren't eye-grabbingly interesting: low views/votes across the board. That isn't to say they aren't *useful*, in fact a lot of the weird/more intricate ones are. This happens everywhere, and isn't a reflection on you personally. Hell, an example from my recent history: I'm more proud of [Getting an Afterglow 360 controller to work on PC](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/282826/28182) question/answer than the [care for a PS2](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/290931/28182) one, yet the latter scored higher because it's a more "interesting" question.

Comment: RE: Your edit, You got upvoted due to what is colloquially known as 'The Meta Effect'. By asking a Meta question you attracted views and votes as people scrutinized your posts. (Note that this can also have a deleterious effect if your posts are bad).

Comment: @Robotnik Thanks for pointing some new things out to me. Actually, I seem to agree (not only, but mainly) with your first point - that answers to narrow technical questions tend to get less upvotes as people don't know what the answerer is talking about. Don't want to be overly self-promotional here, but I'd link a really nice answer I'm *really* proud of, but has 1 vote: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/56008/the-project-sahara-v2/56776#56776 :)